# TCP Choosing optimal window size?

Tags: tcp, tcl, ns2

I know I need to get the RTT but I really don't get how to calculate it.

For some contextualization:

I have a ns2 script which simulates a server and a receiver with 2 routers in the way. All three links - server to first router, first router to second router, second router to receiver - have different transmission speeds.
The propagation delay is 10ms for the first two links and 3ms for the third one.

I'm sending a 3MB file in 1000 bytes packages (TCP's default packet size), 3146 packages total.

I don't want you to calculate it (the RTT) for me of course, I just want to know how to do it. :\

Comment: Are you talking about discovering this by experiment or by putting code inside the simulation system to calculate what value it should use?

Comment: @DonalFellows hm, I don't think it's supposed to be by experiment nor putting code into the script. Just raw math/data analysis.

Comment: In that case, you're not dealing with a real Tcl problem, but rather a networking-simulation problem plus a bit to do with how to tell the simulator to do it. None of which I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Agent/Ping and collect RTT. Here is an example [TCL snippet](https://github.com/Rishabhkandoi/TCP-Congestion-Control-in-NS2/blob/master/Project_tcp_congestion_window/congestion.tcl)

There is only one problem if there is to much trafic de ping packet will be drop (you can see if you collect **trace-all**)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33417015)